# Freeze/pause a long processing task

Tags: windows-7, windows, python, freeze, process

Is it possible to freeze/pause a long processing task (e.g. a 3-day long computation job `python.exe myscript.py`) with Windows 7?

**Or more generally is it possible to pause any Windows process?**

---

(Of course in the case of Python, I could use `atexit` module, save the state on exit, then kill the process and resume later, but this would be out of topic here - I'm looking for a more "general" solution)

Use cases:

1. you start a long processing task using 25% or 50% or 100% of the CPU, but then you want to use the computer normally during a few hours
2. you are on laptop battery for a few hours, and you want to use computer normally, but without using the battery too fast because of the CPU-intensive task: freeze it!

Note: Lowering the process priority in `Task Manager` wouldn't solve the problem: if the rest of computer is idle, the computational-intensive process would still go to 25, 50 or 100% full CPU, and thus 2. is unsolved

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but it might be: https://ss64.com/nt/pssuspend.html, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pssuspend

Comment: This is the answer :)

Comment: Ok @DavidPostill :) But how to use `pssuspend \\workstation64 python` if there are 2 or 3 different processes/instances of the same `python.exe`? Also would there be a `TaskManager++` software, similar to the standard Task Manager, but that would include this in a nice GUI, which a Play/Pause button?

Comment: Use `start` to run your python processes and give them a unique name. Then suspend by name.

Comment: How does `start` allow to give a custom name? Would it also solve this question (the current solution is not really great) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420116/make-python-process-name-more-explicit?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it doesn't. But you can suspend by pid.

Comment: You can suspend processes using [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Resource Monitor (`PERFMON.EXE /res` or *Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Resource Monitor*), you can right-click any process and ‘Suspend’ it (and later ‘Resume’). You can identify your process easily by the CPU usage.
[image: PERFMON.EXE]

There will be a warning that doing so might crash your system, but you can ignore it for non-system processes (but don’t suspend required system-processes, obviously!)

The Resource Monitor is a part of standard Windows (no need to download or install anything); this works under Windows 7 and Windows 10 for sure; I'd think most other version too, but I can't verify it.

Answer (score 1):

I found an even simpler solution:

If the `python.exe` process runs in a Windows `cmd.exe` window, and prints some text every few seconds (logging), then **you can just click anywhere in this window and drag mouse**, this will make a selection visible.
**When a selection is made, the process is paused** (you can check in Task Manager: the process will drop to CPU 0 %).
To resume, just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>!

Very simple way to pause a Python process :)

[image]

PS: to allow this kind of selection in `cmd.exe`, you need to do <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, *Properties*, Enable *Quick edit*.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Aganju's answer, here is how to launch it from <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> with AutoHotkey:

```
!^+Escape::
Run perfmon.exe /res
return
```

(similar to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> which is the regular Task Manager)